# Should I see these processes on an isolated core?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, scheduling

I am trying to verify whether my build of linux is behaving as intended. I am using the `isolcpus` kernel command line argument to isolate one core of a two cored machine simulated on the RISC-V SPIKE simulator. I want to run processes on the isolated core free from interruption.

When I boot into linux `/proc/cmdline` contains `isolcpus=1` as intended. But when I check the core affinity of running processes I see that some are still on cpu1:

```
ps -A -o pid,cmd,psr
  PID CMD                         PSR
    1 init                          0
    2 [kthreadd]                    0
    3 [rcu_gp]                      0
    4 [rcu_par_gp]                  0
    5 [slub_flushwq]                0
    6 [netns]                       0
    7 [kworker/0:0-events]          0
    8 [kworker/0:0H-events_highpr   0
    9 [kworker/u4:0-events_unboun   0
   10 [mm_percpu_wq]                0
   11 [rcu_tasks_trace_kthread]     0
   12 [ksoftirqd/0]                 0
   13 [rcu_sched]                   0
   14 [migration/0]                 0
   15 [kworker/0:1-events]          0
   16 [cpuhp/0]                     0
   17 [cpuhp/1]                     1
   18 [migration/1]                 1
   19 [ksoftirqd/1]                 1
   20 [kworker/1:0-events]          1
   21 [kworker/1:0H]                0
   22 [kdevtmpfs]                   0
   23 [inet_frag_wq]                0
   24 [kauditd]                     0
   25 [khungtaskd]                  0
   26 [oom_reaper]                  0
   27 [writeback]                   0
   28 [kcompactd0]                  0
   29 [kblockd]                     0
   30 [ata_sff]                     0
   31 [kworker/1:1-mm_percpu_wq]    1
   32 [rpciod]                      0
   33 [kworker/0:1H]                0
   34 [xprtiod]                     0
   35 [kworker/u4:1-events_unboun   0
   36 [kswapd0]                     0
   37 [nfsiod]                      0
   38 [khvcd]                       0
   39 [uas]                         0
   40 [mld]                         0
   41 [ipv6_addrconf]               0
   49 [kworker/u4:2-events_unboun   0
   69 /sbin/syslogd -n              0
   73 /sbin/klogd -n                0
   90 -/bin/sh                      0
  110 ps -A -o pid,cmd,psr          0
```

They are only kernel programs which I suspect to be sat on the core listening for if I allocate a task to cpu1 manually.

So my question is: What is the minimal set of processes I should see on the core if I have isolated it correctly? If this set is not empty, what are they doing? And as a bonus, is this `ps` command enough to verify that `isolcpus` is working as I intend?

Note: Something that makes me think that this might not be working is that I have read that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/present` should be the inverse of each other. But I see:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated
1
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/present
0-1
```